# TextField overlaid on ScrollView "Adjust to Fit" TextField not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, scrollview

I have a scroll view overlaid by two text fields, one near the top and one near the bottom. When text in the text field reaches the side constraints the app freezes up and does not adjust the size to fit the width.  Initially, I had a image view overlaid by two text fields and it was working properly. I think this has some relation to the scroll view.

In the interface builder, Adjust to Fit is checked and min font size set. I also have used the following statements and no avail.

```
    topTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    bottomTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Below is a screen shot of the app when it freezes up and screen shot of the layout in Xcode.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something to todo with Auto layout constraints. Double check constraints for scrollview .Follow this [tutorial](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) very well explained step by step how to handle constraints with scrollview.