# Autolayout constraints not being applied iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am making an app with a UIScrollView with some UIButtons in it along with some UILabels. I'm trying it the way outlined [here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html) on apeth.com as was referenced on another SO question. My implementation does not set a contentSize or use a contentView as the scrollView should adjust to the size of it's subviews.

The problem is that the UIButtons and UILabels seem to not have the constraints applied. I had to bunch up my UIButtons and UILabels to fit on the Storyboard so I could see them like so. However, they appear just like this when I run the app. The constraints should work at runtime, but it just seems like they are using the Storyboard rough layout.

[image: UIViews bunched up at end of scrollview in Storyboard]

And this is how it looks on the 5S

[image: UIViews bunched up at end of scrollview on device]

The UIScrollview constraints to superview are
       0
0 UIScrollView 0
       0

The subviews of UIScrollview are as follows

> Subviews - Center vertical
>
> 16-firstButton-4-firstLabel-16-secondButton-4-secondLabel-etc...-16-lastButton-4-lastLabel-16

EDIT: Followed the suggestion in comment and added the label to the button itself to make it simpler and set contentView to 728. Now, I have the problem of the button truncating the button text, which is awful for localization purposes. Please advise.

[image: updated to suggestion with contentView with truncated labels]

Comment: Auto layout with Scrollview is bit tricky you can follow tutorial in this answer and see if it fixes issue for you . http://stackoverflow.com/a/32856894/1180206

Comment: @Imran I followed the tutorial and have the above edit. Do you have any advice on how to deal with this?